# Repeat total count value

Tags: postgresql, count, postgresql-9.5, join

I have a table called *paths* that looks like this:

```
id  parent_id
--  ---------
 1       null
 2          1
 3          2
 4          3
 5          4
 6          5
 7          5
 8          5
 9          5
10          5
11          1
12         11
13         12
14          1
15          2
16         15
17          3
18          2
19         18
20         19
```

I have the query:

```
SELECT count (id) as count_id, id FROM paths where parent_id=5 group by id
```

It returns me:

```
count_id  id
--------  --
1          6
1          8
1          9
1          7
1         10
```

But I want to get the following:

```
total_count  id  parent_id
-----------  --  ---------
5             6          5
5             8          5
5             9          5
5             7          5
5            10          5
```

Since the total count is 5, I want to show 5 in every column.
What I am doing is finding all nodes whose parent id is the specified number, count the nodes and return every found node along with that total number.

If I found nothing, I'd like to have

```
total_count  id    parent_id
-----------  ----  ---------
0            null       null
```

Is there a way to do it? 
I use PostgreSQL 9.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GROUP BY id` is useless in the query, since there is only one row for every `id` (it appears to be the primary key of the table).

What you need a count over the whole result. This is easy using a window aggregate:

```
SELECT count(*) OVER () AS total_count, 
       id, parent_id
FROM paths 
WHERE parent_id = 5 ;
```

---

The last requirement is rather weird but you could have that, too, with a more complicated construct:

```
SELECT count(p.id) OVER () AS total_count, 
       p.id, p.parent_id
FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy
  LEFT JOIN paths AS p
    ON p.parent_id = 5 ;
```

Comment: I would use this solution, even though it doesn't cover the last requirement.

Comment: it is weird because I want to differ the case when the id doesn't exist at all in the table paths from the case when the id doesn't have any children. I think I have a bad explanantion